# What's the quantum operator for the diffusion Green's function?

Tags: operators, greens-functions, many-body, propagator, diffusion

I am trying to understand the following equation about the diffusion Green's function ("Principles of condensed matter physics" by Paul Chaikin, chapter 7.4 Diffusion)
$$n(x,t)=\int G(x-x',t-t')n(x',t')dx'$$
where the Green's function $G(x-x',t-t')$ can be considered the probability $P(x,t|x',t')$.

My question is: Can we find the quantum operator of $G$?

Is it equivalent to the quantum many-body theory definition as $G=\langle\psi^\dagger(x,t)\psi(x',t')\rangle$?

Comment: What do you mean "quantum mechanical proof of this"? It's a result of mathematics that doesn't invoke QM at all

Comment: @KyleKanos In QM we have the definition of the Green function and density operator as the second equation, which is not obvious to me. So I am wondering if there is a general proof based on the evolution of operators or states.

Comment: Proof of what? Can you provide more context about where you found these equations? Also, your title asks about Green's function for diffusion, but the body (& now your comment) looks to be asking something different.

Comment: @KyleKanos Sorry for the confusion. I have made some edits. I mean to prove $\langle\psi^\dagger(x,t)\psi(x,t)\rangle=\int\langle\psi^\dagger(x,t)\psi(x',t')\rangle\langle\psi^\dagger(x',t')\psi(x',t')\rangle dx'$, I quote the first equation from "Principles of condensed matter physics" by Paul Chaikin, chapter 7.4 Diffusion.

Comment: So you've made some variable substitutions, do you now want to *solve* this equation? Or do you want to *verify* that this equation exists/is known/other?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: $n(x,t) = <x|n(t)> = <x|e^{-iH(t - t')}|n(t')> = \int dx' <x|e^{-iH(t-t')}|x'><x'|n(t')> = \int dx' G(x-x',t-t') n(x',t')$

Comment: @bolbteppa Could you explain why $\langle\psi^\dagger (x,t)\psi(x,t)\rangle =\langle x|n(t)\rangle$ and $\langle\psi^\dagger (x,t)\psi (x',t')\rangle =\langle x|e^{-iH(t-t')}|x'\rangle$?

Comment: Using $<x|x'> = \delta(x-x')$ in (7.1.3) $n(x,t) = \sum_a \delta(x-x_a(t)) = \sum_a <x|x_a(t)> = <x|\sum_a |x_a(t)> = <x|n(t)>$ we find $n(x,t) = <x|n(t)> = <x|e^{-iH(t-t')}|n(t')> = \int dx' <x|e^{-iH(t-t')}|x'><x'|n(t')> = \int dx' G(x,t;x',t') n(x',t')$.

Comment: Maybe their (7.4.34) is what you're looking for in their notation

Comment: @bolbteppa Thank you, bol. But your proof might not valid for interacting many-body systems, as $|n(t)\rangle$ as you defined is not the true many body state of the system, thus does not evolve as $e^{-iH(t-t’)}|n(t’)\rangle$.